# Release updates during a phased rollout in App Store Connect

Tags: ios, app-store, app-store-connect

How the phased rollout of App Store Connect works in detail? The official [Apple documentation](https://help.apple.com/app-store-connect/#/dev3d65fcee1) is very poor and doesn't mention a lot of things that matter. Let me formulate some questions.

**The situation**

1. The **current version of my app is 1.0** and is released to everyone in the App Store. The version I **want to release is 2.0 (Build number: 100)** and is a **major update with breaking changes**
2. I start a **phased release** for version **2.0**
3. After 2 days the update has reached **2% of my users (randomly selected)** with automatic updates turned on. I decide to **pause the release** because I found a critical bug
4. I create a version **2.0.1 (Build number: 101)** with the bugfix to **2.0**
5. I create a version **1.0.1 (Build number: 102)** with intent to rollback to **1.0** in case the major update it's not going well

**Questions**

1. **How does the release of an update work during a phased release?** Will version 2.0.1 be released only to the same 2% of the users that already received version 2.0? Or it will be delivered to a completely new 2% of my users?
2. In case it's a new 2% of users:

   2.1  what happens to the 2% of users that are on 2.0 and to the remaining 98% that is still on 1.0?

   2.2. is it true that is completely new 2%? Because if they are randomly selected, potentially there could be an intersection between the old 2% and the new 2%.
3. In case I don't want to proceed with the release of the bugfix 2.0.1 (e.g. I realize that the major update 2.x is not behaving well), what is the strategy to rollback to version 1.x? How can I push 1.0.1 to everyone? Should I cancel the phased released of 2.0 and just submit 1.0.1?

Thanks in advance for the help! I have **read tons of Stackoverflow posts** and I have tried to look everywhere on the web, but I didn't find any clear answer about the topic above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. It will be a different random selection of users

2.1 Nothing special.  They stay on their current version until they update (either automatically or manually).

2.2 As it is a random selection, there could be some overlap

3. You can't.  Version numbers always increase.  You could take your version 1.0 code base and release it as version 2.0.2 or something, but you can't release a new "1.0.x"

To clarify this answer, it is perhaps a bit misleading to use the word "selection".  This implies that when you activate a staged rollout, the App Store somehow chooses the devices that will get the update each day, in advance and the update is "pushed" to those devices.

This is not what happens.

iOS devices periodically check with the App Store to see if updates are available for their installed apps and pull them if auto updates are enabled.

For a given app:

- If a non-staged update is available then the answer is "yes"
- If a staged update is available then the answer is randomly "yes" or "no" with an increasing probability of "yes" during the rollout period, with that probability reaching 100% by the end.
- Either way, if the answer is "yes", it is the most recent version of the app that is installed.

Comment: 2.1. **nothing** means they will stay in the version they are until a new version will reach them?

3. I thought only the build number must increase, not the version. Anyway, assuming that my rollback version will be 2.0.2 (not 1.0.1), how should I proceed?

Comment: Yes, I mean nothing special will happen.  Build numbers must increase within a version as you prepare for that version's release, but once a version is released then the next version must be higher. What do you mean how should you proceed?  You just release a new version like any other release. Even if you don't use staged release,  it everyone will update at once so you always have to handle mixed versions.

Comment: Thanks, you have already helped a lot. With "how should I proceed" I mean: should I stop the phased release for 2.0 and release 2.0.2 to everyone? Or should I first release 2.0 to everyone (i.e. completing the phased rollout) and immediately after 2.0.2 to everyone? I am asking because I didn't understand if you can **stop/cancel** an already started phased release.

Comment: You should release the new version immediately; if there is a bug and you know it, you don't want people running the buggy version.

Comment: I completely agree that I should release the new version immediately, but my question is more about **how to do it** when you have a phased release that is currently going on. How do I do the release of 2.0.2 if there is already the 2.0 (the phased one with the bug) going on? Is there a way to completely stop the phased release so that it doesn't reach the remaining 98% of the users?

Comment: As soon as you release a new version the phased release of the old version stops

Comment: @Paulw11 Do you know where can I find this information properly documented? I always thought that old version would be released to all users since we don't have any control of the rollout of the old version when we publish a new version.

Comment: I don't know of any documentation, but why would you think the old version somehow gets delivered to everyone?  The old version doesn't exist any more as far as the App Store is concerned (apart from last compatible version if your new version excludes some older iOS version).  It behaves the same as if you released 1.0.1 and then 1.0.2 a day later without staged rollout. Some people with auto update on won't have updated to 1.0.1 yet. When auto update runs for them they will be given 1.0.2. They won't get 1.0.1 and then 1.0.2

Comment: Updates aren't pushed to devices, they are pulled by the device when it checks for updates. With a non staged rollout when the devices asks the App Store "is there an update for app X?" The answer is "yes".  With a staged rollout the answer is randomly yes or no, base on a weighting related to the rollout period.  If the answer is "yes" then the device always gets the latest release. There is no way the App Store could give some devices the older version because devices aren't pre-selected for rollout.